# Adding options to dropdown with string values containing spaces causing syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a series links that open menus containing dropdowns and input textboxes to add new options to the dropdowns:

[image]

If I save a value containing no spaces ("hello"), everything works fine, but if a value contains spaces ("hello 2"), I get an exception that says 'Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=hello 2]'

These are the two approaches that I've tried so far that have been unsuccessful:

```
$('.addSetSelect').append('<option value="' + setName + '">' + setName + '</option>');
```

and

```
$('.addSetSelect').append(new Option(setName, setName));
```

I was wondering what is the best way to go about adding option elements to a selectbox that can contain value attributes with spaces?

Comment: Both approaches should add `<option>` elements fine. `[value=hello 2]` might refer to dynamically generated jQuery selector somewhere in the code. Just add quotes to it, so it becomes `[value='hello 2']`.

Comment: I was able to replicate the problem I'm having in my application. It seems that when there are multiple dropdown boxes (as in my program), inputting values with spaces seems to cause a problem. Is this a jQuery bug? [jsfiddle.net/E85BP](http://jsfiddle.net/E85BP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably just running into string concat problems.  This is more fool proof:

```
$('.addSelect').append($('<option></option>').val(setName).text(setName));
```

Comment: `$("<option />").text(setName).appendTo(".addSelect");` is shorter.

Comment: that might be shorter but it doesn't set the value attribute :)  The `<option/>` is ok, I use `<option></option>` for readability (I know, I'm weird).

Comment: You do not need value attribute if it is the same as text inside `<option>` ;) (if only he doesn't use a selector by value attribute, however, it refers to my general comment)

Comment: That's true, good shortcut.  I guess I usually use an id as a value.  If anyone's skeptical I made a fiddle to prove it to myself: http://jsfiddle.net/42Hhq/3/

Comment: I just tried out `$("<option />").text(setName).appendTo(".addSetSelect");` and `$('.addSelect').append($('<option></option>').text(setName));` without `.val()` and seem to still be getting the exception regarding the set value when it contains spaces. I did try it in jsfiddle and everything is good, though, so I'll mark this as the appropriate answer. The associated jsfiddle forked from @Milimetric: http://jsfiddle.net/xjBFM/

Comment: I was able to replicate the problem I'm having in my application. It seems that when there are multiple dropdown boxes (as in my program), inputting values with spaces seems to cause a problem. Is this a jQuery bug? http://jsfiddle.net/E85BP/

Comment: Your problem is on that `valExists` function.  That makes sense, you're making the same string concatenation mistake you were making before :)  Please either take care to create proper selectors: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ or just use the simpler .val() function in a loop to check for existence.